# The max of all possible sequential sums

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Is there a way to write this using formulas.

```
=Max(a, a+b, a+b+c, a+b+c+d, a+b+c+d+e+...)
```

### I don't want to use VBA for this task and I am not sure how to approach this problem.

[Excel sheet expanded with formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xgUhE.png)
[Excel sheet contracted without formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XOLu1.png)

Objectives:

1) For each of the peoples, (Bill, Ben, Katy), I would like to compare the maximum of the sum of only X through time.

For example, in Column J, I would like to know the current Max of the sum of X. Current is the date 1/17/19 because it is the most recent entry.

2) For each of the peoples, (Bill,Ben, Katy), I would like to compare the max of the previous entry to the max of my most recent entry.

For example, in Column K, I would like to compare the Max of the sum of X at 1/5/16 to the max of the sum of X at 1/17/16.

3) I would like Column J and K to recalculate as I bring in new data entries into Column I. As of now, using a solution mentioned below, in Column J, I think I would be using something like this formula:
`=MAX(MMULT(0+(ROW(B9:I9)>=TRANSPOSE(ROW(B9:I9))),B9:I9)`
This solution seems to work if I only have X's going down vertically though.
Also, as new data gets brought in, Column J and K would be pushed to the right, becoming Column K and L.

4) The highlighted region in Column I and J are my output sections that are dependent on the date of Cell B1.

For example, if I were to change the date to 1/1/2016 in Cell B1, Cell I7 would equal -4 Cell J7 would equal True.

If I were to change the date to 1/17/16 in Cell B1, Cell I7 would equal 5 and Cell J7 would equal True.

I've been playing around with this a bit, trying to use SUMIFS to pick up sum of X based on a date criteria.

I thank everyone in advance for all your help, and I apologize if my wording to this problem is unclear. I am a undergraduate student, and have no background in computer/programming/anything of that sort at all. Thank you so much!

Comment: Where shall the variables `a`, `b`, `c`, ... come from? Also: shall this all be in one formula only? Then this will be nearly impossible. But using helper cells it will surely possible.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't understand as you haven't added your expected results in columns I and J of your sheet for the data given.

Comment: I am working out the expected results right now. I'm just having a hard time doing so... How would I take the formula you've provided but calculate it for a dataset that goes horizontal instead of vertical?

Comment: Oh okay, I've tweaked your original formula a bit to =MAX(MMULT(B7:G7,0+(COLUMN(B7:G7)>=TRANSPOSE(COLUMN(B7:G7))))) to answer my question.

Is there any way to apply this formula to get the max of values that are only X's in the criteria row possibly using SUMIFS?

Comment: Okay, so with even more tweaking and experimenting, I have come up with =MAX(MMULT((B7:H7)*(B5:H5="X")*(B4:H4<=B1),0+(COLUMN(B7:H7)>=TRANSPOSE(COLUMN(B7:H7)))))

Comment: Is there a way to have this formula calculating with empty cells in Column H? As of now, I've put in 0's to have it working, but when I empty the cells, it does not calculate...

Comment: Got it!!
=MAX(MMULT((B7:H7<>"")*(B7:H7)*(B5:H5="X")*(B4:H4<=B1),0+(COLUMN(B7:H7)>=TRANSPOSE(COLUMN(B7:H7)))))
  
This is mega-formula seems to do the trick!
XORLX, do you think this is an efficient formula?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `a`, `b`, `c` etc are in a column, then a standard approach will be to use an additional column with a cumulative sum of the values in the input column. Then you can just take the `MAX` of the column with the cumulative sum.

E.g. use of cumulative sum in column B with the input values in column A:

[image]

With `MAX` formula in column C:

[image]

Comment: Hi, thank you for your input. I have done something like how you've posted above, and it definitely meets what I am looking for. I've expanded on my original post above.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming data in `A1:A5`, you can use this `array formula**`:

`=MAX(MMULT(0+(ROW(A1:A5)>=TRANSPOSE(ROW(A1:A5))),A1:A5))`

which, due to its being non-volatile, is preferable to:

`=MAX(SUBTOTAL(9,OFFSET(A1:A5,,,ROW(A1:A5)-MIN(ROW(A1:A5))+1)))`

Regards

***Array formulas are not entered in the same way as 'standard' formulas. Instead of pressing just ENTER, you first hold down CTRL and SHIFT, and only then press ENTER. If you've done it correctly, you'll notice Excel puts curly brackets {} around the formula (though do not attempt to manually insert these yourself).*

Comment: This seems to work. This is one part of a larger question, but I don't know how to word the question so I am asking it piece by piece.

Comment: Sorry, I am new to this site so I am still learning how to use this site. I will add the next part of the question by editing my original post.

Comment: Hi, I've posted my updated question above. I like your solution and it definitely answers my original post. Thank you so much for your input. I've expanded on my original question above.

Comment: I think that if you have working solutions on a concept problem, you should accept the answer (give it a tick etc), and ask a new question when you have a new issue. You have an array formula which solves a calculation problem. If there are other spreadsheet issues, ask another question IMHO.

Comment: Do you recommend that I post my edited post as a new question? I've also given the solutions an upvote, but I don't think it shows because I am a new user...

Comment: I apologize coming off unpolished and rude, I am very new to all this...

Comment: I think I could help you if you add some manually-calculated expected results to your table screenshot, just so it's clear what is being aimed for.

Comment: XOR LX, is there a way to send you my excel sheet or PM you directly?

Comment: Looks like I can't PM... I've updated my original post as you have said...